# Constraining orbitControls maxDistance when targeted, THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, controls

I have a 3rd person RPG style env in three.js. I'm using orbitControls. The controls target the player obj nicely, and I can spin around her no matter where she is in the world.

The issue I've yet to solve is maintaining a fixed zoom distance while moving, that is less than what the maxDist value is set to. So far the only way I have been able to do it is make the min/max values identical. When I set a large maxDistance value - say 5000, as soon as I start moving the player, she moves away from the cam until hitting maxDist.

I would like to be able to set a secondary or temp maxDist value, say 500, as the player is moving, yet still allows for zooming out to maxDist (5000) if desired. Has anyone done anything similar or have suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about setting `minZoom` and `maxZoom` according to your own desire, and just updating the OrbitControls' `target` in every frame to correspond to the position of the player?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing: `this.controls.minDistance = 500; this.controls.maxDistance = 2500;` in the init and: `const pos = this.player.object.position.clone(); pos.y += 100; this.controls.target = pos; this.controls.update();` in the update. No worky.

Comment: It might help if you were able to provide a working demo of your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the .maxDistance every frame in your render loop, before you call controls.update() it's Ok to make a copy of orbit controls and modify it to suit your needs also.

Comment: Hi thanks, but that creates the same problem (or partial solution) as making the min/max values equal - it constrains the zoom, but still auto zooms out upon forward movement (since the initial cam z position is smaller than the maxDist) until it hits whatever max was set. Not sure how I'd modify the orbit controls lib but I can take a look...